# Converting an array into a comma separated list of variables

Tags: php, mysqli

Parameterized mysqli query:

Trying to make a function to cope with a variable number of bind_param parameters, passed as an array to the function.

The switch statement shows just three, but you can imagine how silly it looks with six.

I must be missing something really obvious. Help!

```
function secureQuery($query,$parametersArray){
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($_GLOBAL['db'],$query);
    $paramsCount = extract($parametersArray, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "param");                     
    $paramTypes = str_repeat("s",extract($parametersArray, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "param"));
    switch($paramsCount){
        case 1:
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$paramTypes, $param_0);
            break;
        case 2:
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$paramTypes, $param_0, $param_1);
            break;
        case 3:
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$paramTypes, $param_0, $param_1, $param_2);
            break;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    return $stmt->get_result();
}
```

Comment: note that $db is undefined inside your function

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the code quite a lot to copy it in here. $db is actually defined globally: $_GLOBAL['db']

Answer (score 0):

So why are you trying to do this for individually named variables anyway? Don't bother using that `extract()`, this is what PHP's `...` (splat) operator was designed for

```
$paramTypes = str_repeat("s",count($parametersArray));
```

and

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$paramTypes, ...$parametersArray);
```

Though you may want to put some handling in place for an empty array

Comment: Spot on. Thanks Mark. I'd never come across the splat operator, but had hoped there'd be a simple answer.